# jQuery - setTimout on div for holding content more than x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

So I have 3 characters and a secret character. The secret character should be the .chosen character. Everything good so far. However, I'm trying to display an alert but only when 3 seconds have passed for a chosen character being in the secret character div. At the moment, pressing the keys quickly (where the secret character contains the chosen character for less than 3 secs) triggers the alerts.

```
<div id="peter" class="chosen">peter</div>
<div id="louis">louis</div>
<div id="stewie">stewie</div>

<br><br>
<div id="secret-character"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
if(e.keyCode==38||e.keyCode==40) {
    var prev = $('.chosen').prev();
    var next = $('.chosen').next();

    if(e.keyCode==38){
        $('.chosen').removeClass('chosen'); prev.addClass('chosen');
    }    
    if(e.keyCode==40){
        $('.chosen').removeClass('chosen'); next.addClass('chosen');
    }  

    var timeoutID = null;    

    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
    timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {alert('3 secs secret character!')}, 3e3);


    $('#secret-character').html('Secret Character:'+$('.chosen').html()+'!');                             
}
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/58MJ3/

Comment: Hiya, sorry if I sound bit thick :)) so what exactly is your desired output? content should bot be visible above 3 seconds? I might be able to help you out, thanks

Comment: @Tats_innit No worries:) I only want the alert to happen when the secret-character div has a character name for 3 seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time your keydown handler runs, you're setting the **local** variable `timeoutID` to `null`:

```
var timeoutID = null;
```

and then you clear that empty timer and start a new one:

```
timeoutID = setTimeout(function() {alert('3 secs secret character!')}, 3e3);
```

but when the callback finishes executing, that `timeoutID` goes away since `timeoutID` is a local variable.

I think you want to clear the *previous* timer so `timeoutID` needs to be preserved between calls to your handler. Perhaps you want this:

```
var timeoutID = null;
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    // As before except no `var timeoutID = null` in here...
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/AjaAb/

Comment: so close:) Gotta love programming more when you figure small things like this out. Thanks mu!

Comment: @Wonka: I know all these things from making the same mistaeks that you're making :)